Conflict between `\setmainfont` and `\mainmatter`
I compiled this MWE
\documentclass{toptesi}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Termes}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
This is a sentence.
\end{document}

with
/usr/local/texlive/2024/bin/x86_64-linux/lualatex -interaction=nonstopmode ./foo.tex
echo $? # in Bash this command prints exit code of lualatex, it is 1

Unfortunately, lualatex complains:
luaotfload | db : Reload initiated (formats: otf,ttf,ttc); reason: Font "TeX" not found.
! Font \TU/TeXGyreTermes(0)/m/it/8=name:TeX not loadable: metric data not found
 or bad.
<to be read again> 
G
l.8 \end{document}

If I comment out \mainmatter or \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Termes} (obviously), everything will work.
I'm quite sure that a tlmgr update broke/deprecated something. But I don't know when this was happen. Furthermore, the same issue also happens into another project but I can't find the culprit to write a MWE.
Update
I have just tried with TeXLive 2023 (that on my PC is no more updated since March 2024):
/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux/lualatex -interaction=nonstopmode ./foo.tex
echo $? # it is 0

Everything works!

Works with XeLaTeX though. Not sure why. I don't think this is to do with the distribution, because you should be able to load the font correctly with e.g. book class after loading fontspec.

@cfr Since we can reproduce the error, but load the font correctly using a different class, or with XeLaTeX the problem is unlikely to be caused by some sort of problem with the way the font is installed in the distribution, i.e., it's a problem with the class itself. I suspected polyglossia to be the problem given that the document works with XeLaTeX.

Yes, that's exactly the problem. polyglossia uses the HarfBuzz renderer by default, and this is causing the error. If you load the font with Renderer=Node it will work.

@AlanMunn Cleaned up.

Reported at https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/issues/285

This seems to be a problem with toptesi, with book + fontspec it works without problem. And it seems, that it breaks at the whitespaces in the font names. But you can simply remove them:
\documentclass{toptesi}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeXGyreTermes}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
This is a sentence.
\end{document}

works without error.
AFAIK the problem is somehow related to the usage of polyglossia. If I do not use the toptesi class but the toptesi package and babel instead of polyglossia:
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}% doesn't matter
\usepackage[english,main=italian]{babel}
\usepackage{toptesi}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Termes}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
This is a sentence.
\end{document}

it also seems to work. So maybe you should do a feature request to also use babel with LuaLaTeX not only with PDFLaTeX.
A more minimal example without toptesi would be:
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Termes}
\begin{document}
  \slshape
  This is a sentence.
\end{document}

And a real minimal example would be:
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Renderer=Harfbuzz]{TeX Gyre Termes}
\begin{document}
  \slshape
  This is a sentence.
\end{document}

So as @cfr analyzed IMHO this is a problem of renderer HarfBuzz, which is automatically activated by polyglossia.
As a note: If you move polyglossia after the font setup or load polyglossia with option luatexrenderer=none in the examples using the package, it also works without error. So another workaround for your usage of toptesi class would be:
\documentclass[luatexrenderer=none]{toptesi}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeXGyreTermes}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
This is a sentence.
\end{document}

or
\PassOptionsToPackage{luatexrenderer=none}{polyglossia}
\documentclass{toptesi}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeXGyreTermes}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
This is a sentence.
\end{document}


That was my suspicion too, since the document works with XeLaTeX.

Thank u @AlanMunn and @cabohah for your help! I also solved the same issue on the other project: see this commit. It doesn't use toptesi but article class + beamerarticle. But I couldn't reproduce the issue with a MWE. So I also thought that the issue is not related with toptesi.
Anyway, for the future I will avoid whitespaces in the font names.

Note: Issue reported here.

@miticollo It isn't really related to toptesi. \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Renderer=Harfbuzz]{TeX Gyre Termes} will reproduce.

Reported at https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/issues/285. (The bug linked above was closed as it isn't a polyglossia problem but needs a fix in the engine/loader.)

The problem is not strictly with toptesi if not by the fact that it uses slanted type and provides no way to avoid it. The error appears with \mainmatter because this selects a page style that uses slanted type in the page headers.
Apparently, using the HarfBuzz renderer confuses luaotfload when trying to substitute slanted with italic.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/TeXGyreTermes(0)/m/sl' in size <8> not avail
able
(Font)              Font shape `TU/TeXGyreTermes(0)/m/it' tried instead on inpu
t line 20.
luaotfload | db : Reload initiated (formats: otf,ttf,ttc); reason: Font "TeX" no
t found.
! Font \TU/TeXGyreTermes(0)/m/it/8=name:TeX not loadable: metric data not found
or bad.
<to be read again>
G

This happens when trying to typeset the page header where the class uses slanted type.
A workaround is to use real slanted type.
\documentclass{toptesi}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}[
  %Ligatures=TeX,% unneeded
  SlantedFont=TeX Gyre TermesX,
]

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}

This is a sentence.

\clearpage

Some text

\clearpage

Some text

\end{document}

If you don't want to use TeXGyreTermesX, you can (almost equivalently), slant the font yourself.
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}[
  %Ligatures=TeX,% unneeded
  SlantedFont=*,
  SlantedFeatures={FakeSlant=0.25},
]


