LaTex fails to load accessible font
Here is a minimal test document I name test.tex
\documentclass[12pt,openright]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia} %
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine} %
\begin{document}
  test
\end{document}

I run
$ lualatex test.tex
...
luaotfload | db : Reload initiated (formats: otf,ttf,ttc); reason: Font
"Linux" not found.
! Font \TU/LinuxLibertine(0)/m/it/12=name:Linux not loadable: metric
  data not found or bad.
<to be read again>

I not have this problem until I reinstalled the operating system. An old
document worked fine until I reinstalled.
 $ fc-cache -f -v  |  grep libertine
      /usr/share/fonts/opentype/linux-libertine
      /usr/share/fonts/opentype/linux-libertine: caching, new cache 
contents: 13 fonts, 0 dirs
      /usr/share/fonts/opentype/linux-libertine: skipping, looped directory detected

$ fc-cache -f -v | grep 
libertine /usr/share/fonts/opentype/linux-libertine /usr/share/fonts/opentype/linux-libertine: caching, new cache contents: 13 fonts, 0 dirs /usr/share/fonts/opentype/linux-libertine: skipping, looped directory detected

The font name is linux-libertine but LaTeX looks for linux font.

luatex does not use fontconfig

the font in texlve2024 is /usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/libertine/LinLibertine_R.otf

why do you have a looping directory? nothing to do with tex, but that does not look right at all, especially in directories managed by your distro package manager, where you shouldn't be making changes directly at all. if you didn't change anything, it might be a packaging bug. follow your distro's advice. or fontconfig might be misconfigured. since fontconfig is essentially black magic virtually nobody understands, definitely ask your distro's advice in this case.

Have you tried loading the font using \usepackage[sf=false]{libertine}? This should work with PDFLaTeX, LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX. \setmainfont{Linux Libertine} here also does not work with LuaLaTeX, but the package works. It uses something like \setmainfont[UprightFont=*_R,ItalicFont = *_RI, …]{LinLibertine}.

which package provides those files on your system and for which os/distro? (I ask because arch linux returns 4 non-tex-related results from the main repos alone. alternatively, you can get info about the fonts using otfinfo -i <path-to-font-file>.

@cfr what should that looping error mean? Does not seem to be anything looping when I look at my own.

@daleif do you mean it doesn't complain or that there doesn't seem to be an actual loop?

@cfr it would be nice to know what it referred to? Could it be what it's because the files might be system wide plus in TL?

@daleif no. I don't think so. it thinks there's a circle there - either in the config or in the directory hierarchy itself e.g. a sym link which points to another which points to the first. (but I doubt that's it. more likely in the black box which is fontconfig configuration. I've no reason to think that bar induction. in case you have yet to experience the joys of fc, it is very, very easy to mess up the config.)

@daleif plus I don't think the OP has upstream TL installed.

@cfr so why do we both get that warning...

@daleif because it doesn't depend on upstream TL. I don't think it has anything to do with TL at all. it's purely debian's packaging or config.

related to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/721772/conflict-between-setmainfont-and-mainmatter

https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/issues/285

The cause is a bug in luaotfload. You can reproduce the problem with a more minimal example
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{Linux Libertine}
\begin{document}
  test
\end{document}

If you want to use polyglossia without
HarfBuzz you can do the following
\documentclass[12pt,openright]{book}
\usepackage[luatexrenderer=Node]{polyglossia}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine}
\begin{document}
  test
\end{document}

Or you can use the dev version of luaotfload.

I found that LuaLaTeX's inability to find Linux Libertine is peculiar to the book and memoir classes (perhaps others, but not article). I stumbled on a work-around, which was to join Linux and Libertine with an underscore as in Linux_Libertine. But I do not know if it is legitimate to do so. Please let me know.
The following code works:\
   \documentclass{book}
   \usepackage{polyglossia} % 
   \setmainfont{Linux_Libertine} % 
   \begin{document}
      test
   \end{document}

It works even through in my main document (not this MWE) the L in libertine is dropped as if it were: Linux\_$_\mathrm{L}$ibertine.

I installed fonts-linuxlibertine on my ubunbtu box, fc-cache seems to find it. With that your example fails for me with and without _ (using TL24 upstream)

Isn't it just because the actual font name from the file (see @cfr's comment about otfinfo -i <path-to-font-file>) that the font is actually called Linux Libertine O

Which then interestingly fails under book where it seems it does not like the spaces.... But if one replaces polyglossia by fontspec then it works just fine again.

It seems to be as soon as \chapter exists and polyglossia is used, then it cannot find font names with spaces.

Or at least when something similar to book is loaded. Not sure which test triggers it.

It does not happen with report
